# Turn off outlining permanently for VS2010 ( C/C++ )

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

For some reason I can't turn it off permanently.  When I stop it manually from `Edit->Outlining->Stop Outlining` it's OK but once I close the file and open it again and it's on again. Disabled it in `option->text editor->c/c++->formatting` and nothing. 
Tried editing the `.vssettings` file (or I'm editing wrong file? `C:\Users\%current user%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings`) but something is modifying it back again. I'm out of ideas :(.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Choose `Tools` menu > `Options` menu item.

Expand `Text Editor` then `C/C++` and click on `Formatting`, set `Enable Outlining` to `false`

Note: you may need to reopen the file. The option is technically to enable outlining on file open.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2013 it's not under Formatting. It's here:

Go to:

`Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Advanced`

And then just `uncheck "Enter outlining mode when files open" checkbox`.

And that's it. ;)

Comment: How to do this for HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: No idea. Can't find it. :/ Maybe it will be available in a newer version of VS.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2015 for C/C++ files it's here:
`Options->Text Editor->C/C++->View->Enable Outlining`